# Including a library to call from your JNI classes on Eclipse - Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In the CPP file placed under jni folder along with the header file and Android.mk, I have to make use of an API from a third party library. The library providers gave me two files:

RemoteDesk.h
libremotedesk_client.so

How shall I include these two files? How should the Android.mk file look?

Comment: Add the library to your `LOCAL_LDLIBS` and the header to your `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`.

Comment: Also, copy the .so file to your project's libs/armeabi folder (assuming it's ARM) and load it at runtime using System.loadLibrary("remotedesk_client");

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference this prebuilt library from your *Android.mk*.

I assume your vendor's lib is for armeabi architecture, so place *libremotedesk_client.so* under *./jni/RemoteDeskLib/prebuilts/armeabi/*.  You should ask him for more as the NDK also supports *armeabi-v7a*, *x86*, *x86_64*, *arm64-v8a*, *mips*, *mips64*...

Also place *RemoteDesk.h* under *./jni/RemoteDeskLib/include*:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := remotedesk_client
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := RemoteDeskLib/prebuilts/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libremotedesk_client.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/RemoteDeskLib/include/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := yourLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yourCppSourceCode.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := remotedesk_client
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```